# TypeError: i.createObjectURL is not a function - JS

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

Running some unit test for REACT JS using enzyme and Jest

Ran into this error and cant find the solution

```
  converter.json2csv(header, (err,CSV) => {
  CSV = str2ab('CSV') //error argument should be a string
  var blob = new Blob([CSV], { type: "text/csv" }); //ERROR <<<<< 
  if (blob) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.props.grid+"_Import_Template.csv")
  }
}, {emptyFieldValue: ''})
```

}

1st of all I had  CSV = str2ab(CSV) -  error: Argument should be a string
So I changed into :    CSV = str2ab('CSV')

Here is the render ()

```
<div>
  <button className={'tran-button file-button'} id='template-test-click' onClick={() => {this.downloadTemplate()} }>
   Template
   </button>
```

Here is the test :
When I test for an Id: I get the error above, but when I try class name: node can't be found

```
  beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<ComponentModal {...baseProps} />));

 it("should call click event", () => { 
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({
      grid:{}
   }); 
  wrapper.setState({
                }); 
  wrapper.update() 
 console.log(wrapper.debug())   
 wrapper.find('#template-test-click').at(0).simulate("click");
 });
```

Comment: @skyboyer ANY CLUE ??

Comment: Please edit your post, your code is incomplete in your post. It's hard to read and due to the lack of code, don't know what did you try to do. Make sure your code don't have syntax error.

Comment: Has you managed to fix the issues, I got the same one today, can not test it.